# Windows 10 1809 - Region/language registry keys

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I got two simple question for you guys today, hopefully you can help me since I haven't been able to find it myself for some reason.

For Windows 10 1809 what registry keys controls the following settings?:

- Settings > Time & Language > Region > "Country or region"
- Settings > Time & Language > Language > "Preferred language" order of languages

I've tested quite a bit with the following keys, but they do not seem to control any of these two settings:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Locale > "(Default)" key  
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language > "Default" key  
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language > "InstallLanguage" key  
HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo > "Nation" key  
HKCU\Control Panel\International > "Locale" key  
HKCU\Control Panel\International > "LocaleName" key
```